# can't import kivy properly

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to learn kivy in python and I have built a small program that should display hello world on the screen but when I run it I get:
cannot import name 'app' from 'kivy.app'

code:

```
from kivy.app import app
from kivy.uix.label import label
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return label(text="hello world")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp.run()
```

and I am running this in a virtual enviroment

Comment: it's `App`, not `app` - see that MyApp inherits from `App`. Also import `Label`, not `label` and fix your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good day. As mentioned by [buran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4046632/buran) in the comments of your question, your import code must change to:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
```

Even later in your code, `MyApp` inherits from `App`.

Watch your syntax. Classes generally begin with capital letters.